# Decaying inequality in expectation implies almost sure convergence to zero?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

Is this claim true? The following is my attempt at the proof. I am unsure about the proof because I did not have to use the fact that $X_n\geq 0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Any feedback for confirmation will be greatly appreciated.

**Claim:** Suppose the sequence of nonnegative random variables, $X_n\geq 0$ satisfies $E[x_{n+1}]\leq E[X_n]r$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, where $0<r<1$.Then, $X_n$ converges to zero almost surely.

**Proof:** Given inequality implies $E[X_n]\leq E[X_0]r^n$. For any $\epsilon>0$, Markov inequality yields $P(\{X_n\geq \epsilon\})\leq \cfrac{E[X_n]}{\epsilon}\leq \cfrac{E[X_0]r^n}{\epsilon}$.
Thus, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\{X_n\geq \epsilon\})\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{E[X_0]r^n}{\epsilon}=\cfrac{E[X_0]}{\epsilon}\cfrac{1}{1-r}<\infty$. Therefore by Borel Canteli Lemma, $X_n$ converges to zero almost surely.

Comment: Where is your problem ?

Comment: @TheBridge Would the claim still be true if I took away the assumption $X_n\geq 0$? My problem is mainly self-confidence, I guess. I am new to probability and I am teaching it myself.

Comment: You use the $X_n \ge 0$ condition when applying Markov's inequality.

Comment: @angryavian Oh, yes. Thank you so much. So the claim and the proof are OK?

Comment: Sorry I read your question too fast. To answer your question it is not true in general take the trivial example $X_n = -n $, then for any $0<r<1 $ your inequality is true as $-(n+1) < -n$ but $Lim X_n  = -\infty$ so it's not 0. You need somehow to have a lower bound of  some form on $X_n$ to prevent this.

Comment: @TheBridge So if I assume $X_n\geq 0$, then the claim and the proof are OK? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you let $X$ be any nonnegative random variable with $E[X]=\infty$ and define $X_n=X$ for all $n$, then arguably this is a counter-example because $E[X_{n+1}]\leq E[X_n]r$ reduces to $\infty\leq \infty$.  You just need to assume finite expectations, particularly for $E[X_1]$.

Comment: @Michael Ah, great point. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming finiteness as mentioned in the comments $E[X_{1}]$. By the decreasing we get $\lim_{n}E[X_{n}]=0$. By Fatou's lemma for $X:=\liminf_{n}X_{n}\geq 0$ we get

$$E[X]\leq \liminf_{n}E[X_{n}]=0.$$

So we get $X=0$.

Your approach also works too because it shows that for every $\omega$ there exists $N(\omega)$ so that

$$0\leq X\leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you so much.